# Django one to many model ORM access

Tags: django

I have two models, Person and Classes, both these models do not have any database tables corresponding to it (meta `managed=False`), but are **populated by a custom query**.

Is it possible to get the related fields using the ORM. Example: can I do person.classes and get the related records?

The relationship between the two models is one to many.

Here is an example:
Two models users and departments

```
Users
ref | name
1   | John
2   | Matt

Department
ref | name | chair
1   | IT   | 1
2   | Math | 1


u = User.objects.raw("SELECT ref, name FROM users where ref = 1")
```

Now, if I want to get all the departments that `u` is a chair of, can I do that such that when I do `u.deparments` I get the records? (Note that the objects are created using raw sql).

One way I can think is by writing an instance method, but if there are multiple users I run into performance issues (N+1 query).

Comment: An object data is gathered using a custom query.

Comment: Please provide code samples.

Comment: @knbk It is a raw query

Comment: Ive updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will work assuming you have your model definitions correct, but you didn't show those and i have a feeling that those may need fixed first:

```
User.objects.filter(ref=1).prefetch_related("departments")
```